# Change the color of the underline of AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have my AutoCompleteTextView set to un-focusable but I don't want it to change the color of the underline from blue to grey. Is there a way to override it and change the underline color back to the original blue color while still keeping the AutoCompleteTextView unfocusable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a matter of creating and applying a custom style. The first step is to go to http://android-holo-colors.com/ and generate the drawables and style for Autocomplete. Open the generated archive and copy all of the drawables that contain "edit_text" and "textfield" in their file name into your project.

Now you'll have to go through all of the dpi-specific drawable directories and overwrite the files named:

```
apptheme_textfield_default_holo_light.9.png
```

with the file from the same directory named:

```
apptheme_textfield_activated_holo_light.9.png
```

Now you need to create a the custom style. For API 11+ it will look like this:

```
  <style name="MyAutoCompleteTextView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light</item>
  </style>
```

For older API levels, you'll need an alternative style that inherits from `android:Widget.AutoCompleteTextView`.

You should just be able to apply this style now in your layouts:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/MyAutoCompleteTextView"/>
```