# AutoCompleteTextView change the underline color

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am using an `AutocompleteTextView` in Android app.

How to change the Underline color and also the cursor color?

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535907/change-the-color-of-the-underline-of-autocompletetextview

Comment: thats a 2014 answer. Because material design started in 2015. i am using Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar theme.

Comment: don't you like changing the `colorPrimary` from `colors.xml` file?

Comment: I am using colorprimary a different color already

Answer (score 27):

**Step 1** Define a style in styles.xml

```
<style name="Autocomplete">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Where `colorControlNormal` is the color of the underline when the AutoCompleteTextView has no focus, and `colorControlActivated` is the color of the cursor and underline when it has focus.

**Step 2** Add the style to your AutoCompleteTextView

```
<AutoCompleteTextView  
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Autocomplete"/>
```

Check [this](http://www.materialdoc.com/autocomplete-view/) tutorial of AutoCompleteTextViews for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, edit the colors.xml file and change the colorAccent to your choice of color.  Hint, clicking on the displayed color square will bring up a color pallet.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @drilon-blakqori. If you want to add the same colour scheme to the hint text that also doubles as the label when using `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`, do the following.

Create a new style in your `values\styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="HintText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

And in your xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintText"
    ...>
```

Hope this helps. For more details, you can look [here](https://materialdoc.com/components/text-fields/#how-to-style_1).